# SCSS-Variables does not show in frontend

Tags: html, css, variables, sass, phpstorm

I'm building my first website and wanted my stylesheets to be *.scss.

I'm using PhpStorm with a File Watcher to autocompile (Node.js) and that is working fine with and everything, but if I use like a simple color variable for e.g. a background color it throws no error but it's not showing up on my page.

This is what tried for testing:

```css
$color-red: #FF0000;
$color-green: #00FF00;
$color-blue: #0000FF;
h1 {
  color: $color-red;
}

p {
  color: $color-green;
}

a {
  color: $color-blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.scss">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>A Red Title</h1>
  <p>A green paragraph</p>
  <a href="">A Blue Link</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.scss">
> ```

You are trying to use the raw SASS as a CSS file in the browser. You need to use the compiled CSS file output by the SASS compiler.

Comment: Even though I prefer the method Nidhin Joseph is proposing — I use native CSS variables in all my projects now — this is the correct answer for this specific question.

Answer (score 1):

The approach here is to use `var` which is available within CSS. Please find an example of how you can use `var` below.

```css
:root {
  --color-red: #FF0000;
  --color-green: #00FF00;
  --color-blue: #0000FF;
}

h1 {
  color: var(--color-red);
}

p {
  color: var(--color-green);
}

a {
  color: var(--color-blue);
}
```

```html
<h1>A Red Title</h1>
<p>A green paragraph</p>
<a href="">A Blue Link</a>
```

> **NOTE:** You cannot use `scss` in your browser. If you have `scss` code,
>   you need to complile them to equivalent `css` code before executing
>   them in your browser.

Please refer for more info on [css variables](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp) and [scss compiler](https://sass-lang.com/install)